# Emacs: When regexp query-replacing in a `find-name-dired` results buffer, how to match the newline character?

Tags: emacs, find, dired

I know how to use `C-q C-j` or `C-o` in the query string when doing a query-replace or a query-replace-regex, and that works great.

However, in `find-name-dired`, after I've toggled to select the pertinent files in the `*Find*` buffer, if I then type `Q` and try to use either of those (or several other experiments that also don't work) as the query string, no strings ever match my query, even though I know they're there.

This could be a bug.  But, since this behavior has been the same for a couple decades, it's likely there's something I'm missing.  (Before, I'd always do the find-with-newline/replace file-by-file, but today I need to change too many files for that to be practical.)

Alternatively, if anybody knows of a better way in Emacs to perform a regex replace across many files at once than `find-name-dired`, I'm all ears ...

Answer (score 4):

Note that the documentation of `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace` which is invoked by <kbd>Q</kbd> ends with

> REGEXP should use constructs supported by your local ‘grep’ command.

`grep` can't match multiline patterns.

Comment: Ouch.  That makes me sad.  How would you do a multi-file find-and-replace in Emacs when your pattern has a newline in it?  (Very important question for me.)

Comment: Actually, what I really need in almost all cases where I want a newline in the query is to not leave behind two blank lines in a row in a file.  I suppose I could code a routine to find-and-replace all multiple blank lines in a row in a set of files fairly easily ...